# How to let an HTML image overlap another

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="mainRunner">
    <img src="../App_Themes/Default/images/a.gif" />
    <img src="../App_Themes/Default/images/b.gif" />
</div>
```

I want b.gif to overlap a.gif rather than go on a new line - how can I achieve this?

Comment: Overlap how? do you have an image mockup?

Comment: No answer here offers a responsive method '-'

Answer (score 27):

You would have to use positioning and z-index to get this to work, with changing the images to block level elements and adding a class:

```css
.mainRunner {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.img1 {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.img2 {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -12px;
  left: -12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainRunner">
  <img class="img1" src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTG4mTuuZmylqn_qqviXFh5EPLD_DTsXMIjXT-4XJM0QPtJxw7lXw&t=1" />
  <img class="img2" src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTG4mTuuZmylqn_qqviXFh5EPLD_DTsXMIjXT-4XJM0QPtJxw7lXw&t=1" />
</div>
```

Comment: When I try this, it doesn't work, and when I run the code snippet, the two images don't overlap. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer Updated the answer with code that overlaps the images. Use positive and negative top and left values to move your elements around.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the the containing element (wrapping div) has relative positioning applied.

```
div.mainRunner { position:relative;}
```

After this you can do one of the following.

1. Apply a class name to each image so you can map to it with absolute positioning.

   `div.mainRunner img.classname { position:absolute; top:__;  left:__;}`

Lastly apply z-index to the image class.

```
div.mainRunner img.classname { position:absolute; top:__; left:__; z-index:50;}
```

And for the second image;

```
div.mainRunner img.classname { position:absolute; top:__; left:__; z-index:51;}
```

If you have no control over applying classes to the images then do this (on the assumption that only 2 images will be in this div;

```
div.mainRunner img.classname:first-child { position:absolute; top:__; left:__; z-index:50;}
div.mainRunner img.classname { position:absolute; top:__; left:__; z-index:51;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute positioning (please don't), or negative margins with `display:inline`.

Comment: Absolute is fine if, say, you need a sidebar to persist regardless of where you scroll, but I have seen some attrocious sites that try to use absolute positioning on everything and it turns out horrible. If you move one thing, you end up restructuring your entire site, whereas if they would have used relative positioning, everything would have fallen into place. It's not bad per se, but in my opinion it should be avoided where possible.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="float:right">
<svg width="338" height="104">
  <clipPath id="myContainer">
    <rect width="338" height="104"></rect>
  </clipPath>
  <image width="338" height="104" xlink:href="https://www.edoardovignati.it/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/overlap-sunset.png" clip-path="url(#myContainer)"></image>
  <image width="338" height="104" xlink:href="https://www.edoardovignati.it/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/overlap-mountain.png" clip-path="url(#myContainer)"></image>
</svg>
</div>
```

References: https://www.edoardovignati.it/solved-overlap-images-in-html/

Comment: Don't use `<center>`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center