# Layer multiple images in one html table cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple HTML table with a grid of images. But now I'd like one cell to be able to contain multiple layered images as some of them are partially transparent. Making all of the images `position: absolute` makes the whole table combine into one square though.
This the structure I have now; In this example, the stone images should be on the sand images that are now (wrongly) above them. (And the coin image should be on the stone image)

```css
.field {
  border: none;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

.field tr, .field td {
  border: none;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.field img {
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
```

```html
<table class="field">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hgT9iT/rock_1.png">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hgT9iT/rock_1.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/eFMUiT/coin.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hgT9iT/rock_1.png">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hgT9iT/rock_1.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This question [Layering images inside a table-cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184089/layering-images-inside-a-table-cell?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) is similar but isn't quite the same and didn't get any satisfactory answers for this problem.

**Clarification:**
If I simply set the enclosing elements of the images to `position: relative` and the images to `position: absolute` all the images end up in the top left corner of the screen. I have a grid of many cells of which each may have multiple layered images!

Comment: use z index property in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer, setting `position: relative;` on the table cells is completely correct.

The problem, for your example, is when you set `position: absolute;` on an element it doesn't take up space.  So with no other content, your table cells all collapse to size 0, and the images appear to stack since they are all relatively positioned to the same (0, 0) origin.

You *also* need to give the table cells size:

```
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
```

Full example:

```css
.field {
  border: none;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

.field tr, .field td {
  border: none;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

.field img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<table class="field">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hgT9iT/rock_1.png">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hgT9iT/rock_1.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/eFMUiT/coin.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hgT9iT/rock_1.png">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hgT9iT/rock_1.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

using position relative in a td element can help you to set your images in a position absolute

```css
table td {
  position:relative;
}

.absolute-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 73px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="absolute-img">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have many images in the table and they shouldn't be offsetted but layered directly on top of each other in each cell. If I apply this to all the images in my table they all combine into one image in the top left corner of the page.

Answer (score 0):

By telling the browser how big elements have to be things can be put in their correct locations.

Define the height on the tr element of 32 pixels.
Define the width on the td element of 32 pixels.

We now have rows of the correct height and boxes of the correct width.

Set the td element to position: relative
Set the img element to position absolute.

It will be absolutely positioned to the td element you made relative.

Set the img element to `top: 0px; bottom 0px;`

```css
.field {
  border: none;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

.field tr, .field td {
  border: none;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;  
}

.field td {
  position: relative;
  width: 32px;
}

.field tr {
   height: 32px;
   
}
.field img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
```

```html
<table class="field">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hgT9iT/rock_1.png">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hgT9iT/rock_1.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/eFMUiT/coin.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hgT9iT/rock_1.png">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hgT9iT/rock_1.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know how big the imgs are, set their respective height and width to the td, then position absolute on the imgs to take them out of the flow, position:relative on the td so the imgs be raltive to them, and don't go outside.

```css
.field {
  border: none;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

.field tr,
.field td {
  border: none;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.field td {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position: relative;
}

.field img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
```

```html
<table class="field">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hgT9iT/rock_1.png">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hgT9iT/rock_1.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/eFMUiT/coin.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hgT9iT/rock_1.png">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hTXDA8/land.png">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hgT9iT/rock_1.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```