# Bootstrap: How can set an image on another image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my page i have 2 images that i want show one of them on the another one, this is my code, how can i set images:

```
<div class="profile-image img-responsive">
   <img src="images/pro.png"/>
   <img src="images/2.png" class="img-circle">
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/436Qz/4/)

I want to set `2.png` onto the left and bottom `pro.png`  like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182170/how-to-let-an-html-image-overlap-another

Comment: @bnuhero: i edit my code to this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/436Qz/7/), panel and images not responsive how can i fix it?

Answer (score 4):

The following code will display the second image over the first image. All the images and the image panel are responsive.

1.CSS

```
.profile-img {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}

.img-responsive {
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
}

.img-circle {
position:absolute;
z-index:99;
left:10px;
bottom:-50%;
}
```

2.HTML

```
<div class="profile-img">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="images/pro.png" />
  <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="images/2.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

@bnuhero's answer is very good, and I would change it just a little.

First, basing off the jsfiddle, encapsulate the two images in a relative div. This will allow the image placed on top, when defined as "absolute" to be placed relative to the parent div, rather than relative to the entire window.

```
<div class="header-image">
        <div class="profile-image" style="margin: 50px auto;">
            <img src="http://s9.postimg.org/41fwo4k4v/pro.png" class="img-responsive"/>
            <img src="http://s24.postimg.org/on764040x/image.png" class="img-circle img-responsive img-on-top">
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Next, make a rule to define the realtive div. And make an additional class or id to target the image to be placed on top. Writing the rules with the same 'img-circle' class will interfere with the default 'img-circle' rules setup by Bootstrap

```
.header-image {
position:relative;
}

.img-on-top {
position:absolute;
z-index:99;
left:10px;
bottom:-50%;
}
```

Updated jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Bavc_Am/jG9bP/1/

Comment: thanks, and how can set  `image.png ` be responsive? because now it is not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Update your css to this

```
.img-circle {
border-radius: 50%;
position: relative;
top: -69px;
left: 10px;
}
```